# Is there a way to get my .js file to either self destruct, or rename itself, or move itself to a new location after one time use

Tags: javascript

So i have a file (file.js) and basically it tells a config file to import bookmarks to firefox from another .html file, I need to make it so after file.js runs the first time when someone opens firefox, that the file (file.js) either renames, deletes itself, or moves to a different location.

The file currently as follows

```
pref("general.config.obscure_value", 0);

pref("general.config.filename","file.cfg");
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't think you can do this with Client Side scripting

Comment: In what environment/runtime context?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're working with, but if you're using the file to set preferences, why not set a "file-loaded" preference (or something similar) to true, and check that preference before running the rest of the file.

Comment: Deleting the file is possible, but rather you should set a flag somewhere when the process successfully ran, and wrap your code in an if-statement.

Answer (score 0):

Figured a workaround for what i was attempting, used a firefox config to auto export bookmarks back into the file I imported from, thus enabling me to have a default list of bookmarks for new users, but allowing them to add their own as well.